# TFS2018: Use npm publish task to release a built npm package

Tags: tfs

I have a build that creates an npm package (tgz). I would like to add a release pipline to publish this package to our npm server.

The package is available from the artifacts and I can download it in the release pipline. But to publish it with the NPM Task I need its exact name, which has the version number in it.

```
npm publish mypackage-1.0.0.tgz
```

I cannot see any way to get this version number or the full filename of the artifact in the release pipline.

I could probably use a powershell script to do this, but then I am missing the NPM credentials that I configured in TFS.

Am I supposed to do this differently? Am I missing something?

Comment: why not use the powershell to find the file and set the filename as a new variable for the current release-process, then you could use the npm-publish task with the configured credentials

Comment: @D.J. I came to a similar conclusion. I think I misinterpreted the docs a little: "Note that the updated variable value is scoped to the job being executed, and does not flow across jobs or stages." I was not entirely sure what job or stage means in this context (this cleared up, after reading more docs :-) ). But it seems to work fine with a Variable. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the powershell to find the file and set the filename as a new variable for the current release-process, then you could use the npm-publish task with the configured credentials